# Consumir WS com javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, soap

Estou usando o SoapUI para fazer o teste no WS:
[image: Raw do XML]

Outra imagem que mostra a autenticação para consumir o XML:
[image: Visão usando soapUi]

Só que quando eu tento consumir o mesmo xml só que através do javascript, eu não consigo (acho que falta conhecimento técnico)

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
    var url = 'http://SERVIDOR:PORTA/wsConsultaSQL/IwsConsultaSQL';
    var method = 'POST';
    var postData =
      '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tot="http://www.totvs.com/">\n'
      + '    <soapenv:Header/>\n'
      + '  <soapenv:Body>\n'
      + '  <tot:RealizarConsultaSQL>\n'
      + '  <tot:codSentenca>06</tot:codSentenca>\n'
      + '  <tot:codColigada>1</tot:codColigada>\n'
      + '  <tot:codSistema>S</tot:codSistema>\n'
      + '  <tot:parameters>NUMEROINSCRICAO=192;IDPS=6</tot:parameters>\n'
      + '  </tot:RealizarConsultaSQL>\n'
      + '  </soapenv:Body>\n'
      + '  </soapenv:Envelope>\n';
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("POST", url, true);
    req.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8');
    req.setRequestHeader('SOAPAction', '');
    req.withCredentials = true;
    req.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa('milrak.pessoa' + ":" + 'MINHASENHA'))
    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (req.readyState != 4) return;
      if (req.status != 200 && req.status != 304) {
        console.log('HTTP error ' + req.status);
        return;
      }
      console.log(req.responseText);
    }
    if (req.readyState == 4) return;
    req.send(postData);
  });
```

O Erro retornado é:
[image: Erro retornado do código]

Alguém já fez isso com javascript ou jquery?

Comment: O cabeçalho `SOAPAction` deveria estar vazio?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss andei lendo umas coisas, será que é por conta das políticas segurança, que não posso fazer ou receber requisição de um mesmo servidor. (usando javascript)